# Following pointer usage are not recommended. Especially for helping in automatic parallelization

Tags: c, pointers, parallel-processing

Can anyone give me an example for these statements. I read it somewhere, where it was mentioned that these kind of pointer usage are not recommended. (These are basically meant for helping in automatic parallelization, if we avoid these kind of pointer usage. It would be great if anyone can through some light on this also.)

1) "Pointer casts except for heap allocation site."

2) "Pointer arithmetic. (When we access the region pointed to by a pointer, use
dereference operator (*) or index operator ([ ]) on the pointer variable
without updating pointer value.) "

3) "Updating pointer value in a conditional branch or a loop except for heap
allocation site."

4) "Passing arguments of function as pointer to different offset of same
dimension of an array. (Thus, regions pointed to by function arguments in
callee never overlapped.) "

5) "Reusing a heap object as a temporal buffer. (Reuse of heap can be an
obstacle of parallelism extraction since it is more difficult to analyze the
reuse of a heap object than reuse of an ordinaly variable.) "

6) "Index accesses to an array member of an array of structures. (If an array of
structures has an array member, pass one element of the array of structures
as an argument of a function and access the member in the callee function.) "

Comment: Essentially it just boils down to: use arrays rather than pointers if you want your compiler to be able to parallelise your code.

Answer (score 1):

2)

```
char *x = "lsdjjasd", *y;
int i;

// Access by index (x still points to beginning of string)
for (i=0; x[i]; i++) {
  x[i] = toupper(x[i]);
}

// Pointer arithemtic (modifying x) 
for (; *x; x++) {
  *x = toupper(*x);
}
// x now points to the end of the string
```